# Aligning HTML form fields - Converting to CSS

Tags: html, css, forms

I've started to design a form, and I've done it the obvious way (to me) but this really seems like the wrong way. I don't think I should be using tables, but rather CSS:

```
<form action="test.php">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td><td><input type="text" id="prjname" size="30"/></td>
            <td align="right">Design type</td><td align="right"><select id="prjdesigntype">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">- Select one -</option>
                </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description</td><td colspan="3"><input type="text" size="80" id="prjdesc" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Can anyone suggest a better way or doing the above? Specifically, I want it to look nice, for example the lining up of the "select" box with the end of the description box like above.

I've tried using DIVs, but I can't figure out how to align text boxes on one line with a text box on a previous line.

Comment: Do you have an image of the layout you'd like to achieve?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=css%20forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you would do well to start using divs and css, because then you will have more control over your elements. Try this code.

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: auto; margin: auto;">
<form>
<input type="text" name="prjname" id="prjname" size="30" placeholder="Enter your name .." style="float:left; clear:none; padding-left: 15px;"/>
<select id="prjdesigntype"style="float: right; clear:none;" >
    <option value="0" selected="selected">- Select one -</option>
</select>
<input type="text" size="80" id="prjdesc" placeholder="Enter the description .." style="float:left; clear:both; width: 500px; padding-left: 15px;"/>

</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, but its missing the labels, and I can't figure out how to size the text box to fit the remaining size - setting it to 100% just uses up a whole new line rather than whatever is left over.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use textarea tag for description, because input tag is not suitable for long text and it wont look good.

Answer (score -1):

Give this a go

```
    <form action="test.php">

    <div style="margin-bottom:5px;">
        <div style="float:right;">
            Design type
            <select id="prjdesigntype">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">
                    - Select one option
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            Name
            <input type="text" id="prjname" size="30"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        Description <input type="text" size="60" id="prjdesc" />
    </div>

</form>
```

Once you get your head around it, divs and CSS are much easier than tables :)

Also, this might belong more on http://ux.stackexchange.com, but it tends to be better for usability to have all your form elements in one column rather than two, so you might wish to do that.